# GDB - providing source code path for a binary which doesnt have symbols

Tags: c, gdb

Is it possible to provide source code path if I don't have symbol table in the binary or otherwise. But I just know from which source code base the binary was created.

If I remember correctly gdb supports that but I am forgetting it after so many years.

Answer (score 1):

> If I remember correctly gdb supports that

No, it does not.

> But I just know from which source code base the binary was created.

That is not very useful to GDB.

In order to perform source-level debugging, GDB needs to know which addresses correspond to which lines of which sources (debug line table), and which variables have which types/sizes (and where they are declared).

That information is emitted by the compiler when you compile with `-g`, and without it source level debugging is impossible.